# Postgres n_tup_ins vs row count mismatch for a table which was never analyzed

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I'm trying to figure out why no analyze job was ever performed on a table with more than 1 million rows.
If I run the following query:

```
select count(*) from variant
```

I get `1,668,422`

However when I retrieve the statistics on that same table:

```
SELECT relname,
n_tup_ins, n_tup_upd, n_tup_del,
n_live_tup, n_dead_tup,
last_vacuum, last_autoanalyze
FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE relname = 'variant';

          relname           | n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | last_vacuum | last_autoanalyze
----------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------
 variant_analysis_dependent |    140514 |       530 |         0 |     140514 |        104 |             | 
(1 row)
```

We can see that no analysis was ever performed. Then my expectation would be for `n_tup_ins` to be equal or greater than the amount of rows from the first query (and `n_live_tup` to be equal). Also `n_tup_ins - n_dead_tup` should be equal to `n_live_tup`

I have the following values for the settings:

```
SELECT name, setting, short_desc from pg_settings where category like 'Autovacuum';
                name                 |  setting  |                                        short_desc                                         
-------------------------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 autovacuum                          | on        | Starts the autovacuum subprocess.
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1       | Number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze as a fraction of reltuples.
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50        | Minimum number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze.
```

So even with the tuple counts from the statistics, if we apply the formula `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor * number of tuples + autovacuum_analyze_threshold`, we should get `0.1 * 140514 + 50 = 14101.4`, less than `n_tup_ins = 140514`, so the analyze job should be triggered, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is in pg_class for this table?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The value of reltuples is  1.496771e+06, which is way closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'number of tuples' to be used in your formula comes from pg_class, not from pg_stat_user_tables.  So this observation is easy to explain if your server has crashed, or had pg_stat_reset() or kin invoked on it at the "right/wrong" time.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to fix this? Maybe by running the analyze job manually the correct values will be recalculated and subsequently automatic analyze jobs will be triggered?